# Cloning the same git repo second time in laravel

Tags: git, laravel-5

Do we need to do php artisan key:generate after cloning the same git repo second time also?
I did php artisan key:generate when i cloned for first time.
I am going to clone for second time with updated repo by my colleges.

Comment: Are you cloning a copy of the official Laravel git repository, or are you cloning a git repository created by you colleagues, which will be an application based on the Laravel framework?

Comment: I m cloning the git repo createsd my myself, actually m developing the application in my localhost and uploading in git whenever i write in app, , and then cloning updated repo in my life server.

Comment: Please add the information in your comment to your question itself. People often do not read comments, and this is useful information.